# How can I pause the audio source and animation at the same time in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-player, pause

I have a scene in my mobile where the animation and audio source can pause. I already know the code for animation. I would like my audio source can pause too. This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;

using System.Collections;

public class Pause : MonoBehaviour {

    public Canvas MainCanvas;
    public Button PauseButton;
    public Canvas Canvas;

    public void start() {
        OnUnPause();
    }
    public void OnPause()
    {
        Canvas.enabled = true;
        PauseButton.enabled = false;
        if (MainCanvas.GetComponent<Animator> ().enabled = false) {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }

        if (MainCanvas.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().enabled = false) {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
```

}

```
    public void OnUnPause()
    {
        Canvas.enabled = false;
        PauseButton.enabled = true;
        if (MainCanvas.GetComponent<Animator> ().enabled = true) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
          if (MainCanvas.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().enabled = true) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
```

}
        public void startLevel(){

```
    Application.LoadLevel("ABC");
}
    public void finishLevel(){

        Application.LoadLevel ("Classroom");

}
}
```

Comment: I don't see any audio code in your code. Maybe you should just google "Unity stop Audio" and try the solution you find, then tell us what problems you are having.

Comment: @Programmer I delete the audio part in my code because It doesn't pause at all. I don't want the audio to stop but it will pause.

Comment: Please include it. You include what you tried that's no working then explain what is not working and what you expect it to do then we help you. Just don't expect us to write it for you. You can tag C# to this question since it is in C# and will make many other Unity C# programmers to help.

Comment: After if statement i used else if (MainCanvas.GetComponent<AudioSource>().enabled = false) { Time.timeScale = 0; }

Comment: You should include that code in the post itself, not here in the comments. I tried to edit for tags and grammar, but it appears the post is "mostly code". I suggest adding [C#] tag and changing [audio] tag for [audio-player] following suggestion in the audio tag wiki.

Comment: I already re-edit my post. Please bear withe me. I'm newbie in Unity and posting question like this.

Answer (score 0):

For Animation If you set Timescale to zero it will automatically stops.

For AudioSource it would be like this in Pause() function

```
'public void OnPause()
{
    Canvas.enabled = true;
    PauseButton.enabled = false;
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    if (MainCanvas.GetComponent<AudioSource> ()) 
    {
        MainCanvas.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Stop();
    }
}`
```